# How to access ADLS blob containers from Databricks using User Assigned Identity

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have ADLS storage account with blob containers. I have successfully mounted ADLS with Service Principal in Databricks and able to do my necessary transformations on the Data.

Now I'm in a process of using User Assigned Managed Identities to avoid keeping the secrets in my code. For the process, I have created required Managed Identity and enabled it to my service principal by assigning necessary role in the Storage account.

My question is how can I use the managed Identity or how can I do my transformation on the ADLS storage from Databricks without mounting or using secrets?

Please suggest a working solution or any helpful forum for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can authenticate automatically to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1
> (ADLS Gen1) and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (ADLS Gen2) from Azure
> Databricks clusters using the same Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)
> identity that you use to log into Azure Databricks. When you enable
> Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough for your cluster,
> commands that you run on that cluster can read and write data in Azure
> Data Lake Storage without requiring you to configure service principal
> credentials for access to storage.

**Enable Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough for a High Concurrency cluster**

High concurrency clusters can be shared by multiple users. They support only Python and SQL with Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough.

1. When you create a cluster, set Cluster Mode to High Concurrency.
2. Under Advanced Options, select Enable credential passthrough for user-level data access and only allow Python and SQL commands.

[image]

**Enable Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough for a Standard cluster**

1. When you create a cluster, set the Cluster Mode to Standard.
2. Under Advanced Options, select Enable credential passthrough for user-level data access and select the user name from the Single User Access drop-down.

[image]

**Access Azure Data Lake Storage directly using credential passthrough**

After configuring Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough and creating storage containers, you can access data directly in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 using an `adl://` path and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using an `abfss://` path.

Example:

Python - `spark.read.csv("adl://<storage-account-name>.azuredatalakestore.net/MyData.csv").collect()`

Refer this offcicial documentation: [Access Azure Data Lake Storage using Azure Active Directory credential passthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough)

Comment: I understood the flow through the credential passthrough.
I have already completed my configuration by mounting the service principal and ADLS gen 2 storage, stored all my secrets in Key Vault. But i want to change this setup by using Managed Identities. 

I have created a User assigned managed Identity and enabled the access to my storage account and databricks workspace. But i dont know how to access the data in my storage account. 

All I want to is to avoid using secrets in my code and multiple service principals in my setup.
I guess I'm not finding exact documentation for this.